# Attempting to generate a heat map like in this figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame

```
Response TO CHEMOTHERAPY    Gene    CCF
Responders                  POLQ    1
Responders                 CDKN2A   1
Responders                  TP53    1
Responders              CCDC102B    0.906729075
Non-responders           CCDC102B   1
Non-responders           CCDC102B   1
Non-responders           CCDC102B   1
Non-responders             TSHZ3    1
Non-responders             PIK3CA   1
Responders                 SLIT2    1
Non-responders              SLIT2   1
```

I have `two groups of patients`; `Responders to chemotherapy and non-responders`. For each group I have calculated `cancer cell faction (CCF)` for a fixed set of genes so that an individual gene has several reads in each group

If `CCF = 1` the gene clonal and if CCF < 1 gene is sub clonal, for a given gene for each group, I therefore would have the number of clonal and sub clonal for this gene, for example 2 clonal 7 sub clonal which would be 2/7 something like the below heat map

[image]

By your kindly code I produced this

[image]

Which is not well informative

This is another potential example heat map

[image]

Which show the clonal frequency for each group

By the way thanks for your kindness

I don't know how to use `dput()` but this is my complete data

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ol7m4nlkuyuy85a/c1.txt?dl=0

Comment: What have you tried? You could use `geom_rect` after setting `x` and `y` `aes` to `Sample` and `Gene`.

Comment: There is multiple examples of how to do heatmap with `ggplot2` on SO, for example, you can start by taking a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406394/how-to-produce-a-heatmap-with-ggplot2/8406774#8406774 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290364/heatmap-with-values-ggplot2 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60162198/customizing-heatmap-appearance-using-ggplot-in-r/60163171#60163171 ... Try to reproduce those examples and then you will know how to deal with your data

Answer (score 1):

Given the lack of effort from the OP, probably I shouldn't have wasted my time on this question with a lot of problems:

i) The question is not reproducible, the OP should have supplied their data with `dput()`.

ii) The data as pasted above does not quite make sense to me, why would you have three readings from the same gene and even in such a case how should these replicates be represented in a heatmap?

iii) The question is not specific enough and should not go like "how can I generate a heatmap" and should be more like "in an attempt to generate a heatmap like in this figure I have tried this piece of code but ..."

Having said these, and after downvoting the question, here is a solution leveraging the `ComplexHeatmap` package:

```
library(data.table)
library(ComplexHeatmap)

my_data <-
"
Sample  Gene    CCF
Sample1 POLQ    1
Sample1 CDKN2A  1
Sample1 TP53    1
Sample1 CCDC102B    0.906729075
Sample1 CCDC102B    1
Sample1 CCDC102B    1
Sample1 CCDC102B    1
Sample2 TSHZ3   1
Sample2 PIK3CA  1
Sample2 SLIT2   1
Sample2 SLIT2   1
"

my_data <- fread(my_data)

my_data <- dcast.data.table(my_data, 
                            formula = Gene ~ Sample,
                            value.var = "CCF",
                            fun=mean)

# dcast generates NA values as the provided data does not have values for each gene
my_data[is.na(my_data)] <- 0

# Heatmap() expects a matrix input
my_matrix <- as.matrix(my_data[,c("Sample1", "Sample2")])
rownames(my_matrix) <- my_data$Gene

Heatmap(my_matrix,
        cell_fun = function(j, i, x, y, width, height, fill) {
          grid.text(my_matrix[i, j], x, y, gp = gpar(fontsize = 10))})
```

This is how the data look after `dcast`, in which multiple entries per gene (my point ii above) is summarized with `mean()`:

```
> head(my_matrix)
           Sample1 Sample2
CCDC102B 0.9766823       0
CDKN2A   1.0000000       0
PIK3CA   0.0000000       1
POLQ     1.0000000       0
SLIT2    0.0000000       1
TP53     1.0000000       0
```

Here is the resulting heatmap:

[image]

Comment: Sorry please don't close my question, I have edited that and I am certain I know what I want and what is the final goal